# Cannot keep session when using request library

Tags: python, selenium-rc, pycharm

I have a problem with Selenium RC and writing tests.

When I pass valid a url into the browser, I get json data with `"sessionExists":True` and the rest of json data, which is ok. However, when I pass the same url into my code in PyCharm using the `requests.get()` method, I get json data with `"sessionsExists:False"` and the rest of json data is not fulfilled properly.

I use javascript to get a valid session id, which is in the URL, so I am sure that the session id is valid.

#### Enviroment:

- FF 22.00
- Selenium RC - 2.35
- PyCharm - 3.01